# Reduce nested for loops and if statements using Iterator Blocks?

Tags: c#, design-patterns

Is it possible to reduce this long nested for loops and if conditions to increase its readability and to optimize it for future reference.

While writing code for my scheduling app, I ended up with a method as shown below. Really, I have a data structure like [this](http://pastie.org/7097616). Here, I checks - Is there any stages (Inside LCycle) which using same Tool at same time and If its found so, another method `LCycleTimeShift` is called to make a rearrangment.

But I want to check whether the new arrangement is adaptable and the for loop counter is reset so that it will check the new arrangment again. I think this is not the better way to write the code for  better readabilty. A little research on the topic found that Enumerators can help me in this. But I don't know how can I accomplish this with the following code.

```
public List<LCycle> ToolArrangment(List<LCycle> TimeLineInit)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < TimeLineInit.Count; i++)//Each LIfeCycles In TimeLine
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < TimeLineInit[i].Stage.Count; j++)//Each Stages inTimeLine
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < i; k++)//Each L esvd =ifeCycles Upto Current LifeCycle
            {
                for (int l = 0; l < TimeLineInit[k].Stage.Count; l++)//Each Stages of (LifeCycle upto current LifeCycle) 
                {
                    for (int m = 0; m < TimeLineInit[i].Stage[j].ToolList.Count; m++)//each tools in stage of timelkine
                    {
                        for (int n = 0; n < TimeLineInit[k].Stage[l].ToolList.Count;n++ )// Each tools In that stage (for loop outer of outer)
                        {
                            if (TimeLineInit[i].Stage[j].ToolList[m].ToolName == TimeLineInit[k].Stage[l].ToolList[n].ToolName)//If both tools are same (satidfying above for loop conditions)
                            {
                                if (IsTimeOverLaps(TimeLineInit[i].Stage[j].StageSpan, TimeLineInit[k].Stage[l].StageSpan))
                                {//tool using at same time.
                                    Stage ReplaceStage = TimeLineInit[i].Stage[j].DeepCopy();//Taking Copy of stage Span to make time shift
                                    Double TimeDifference=(ReplaceStage.StageSpan.ToTime-ReplaceStage.StageSpan.FromTime).TotalMinutes;//Calculating required time shift
                                    ReplaceStage.StageSpan.FromTime=TimeLineInit[k].Stage[l].StageSpan.ToTime;//FromTime changed accordingly
                                    ReplaceStage.StageSpan.ToTime=ReplaceStage.StageSpan.ToTime.AddMinutes(TimeDifference);//To Time Changed accordingly
                                    LCycleTimeShift(TimeLineInit[i], ReplaceStage);//passing refernce
                                    j = 0; k = 0; l = 0; m = 0; n = 0;//Counter Reset to validate the new arrangment
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return TimeLineInit;
}
```

Comment: o.0 do you really need that many `for` loops?

Comment: Does it matter which of 2 overlapping stages actually gets rescheduled, or you're allowed to change any of them?

Comment: yes I need @Tyriar

Comment: @almaz the later one only rescheduled

Comment: You should consider using `foreach` instead of `for` for collections.

Comment: And that counter reset is a terrible thing to do. Especially since I think it won't work the way you expect. (It won't start looping from the topmost `for`.)

Comment: @svick you meant it won't start from 0. or not at all

Comment: That's some serious for loop nesting

Comment: Have to rethink this. How would prof oaks do it?

Comment: @SmartLemon Thats what me too wanted to know. But everyone pointing wats bad in this code not how to fix

Comment: When resetting the values at the bottom you are creating an infinite loop inside the last loop. Unless you have done something to get around this...

Comment: @SmartLemon But it won't run infinity. Another method called in between will really fix it. But what should I do if I don't know how much time the for loop executes. I want to `LCycleTimeShift` until the list get optimized

Comment: This smells like feature envy (http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?FeatureEnvySmell) and it's breaking the Law of Demeter (http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?LawOfDemeter). Clean it up, move logic into respective classes. The inner logic most definately belongs in Stage or Tool, and some of the fors probably belong in LCycle. The code you pasted should read something like foreach(var cycle in TimeLineInit) cycle.MakeTimeShifts();

Comment: @Lars-Erik But why always foreach gets more preference. Most of the advices was about foreach

Comment: I agree with @Lars-Erik. You would need two for loops, though. 
I also believe these `List<LCycle> TimeLineInit` is in some aggregate root [That is, whatever object owns this list]. And this method method belongs there. 
And call it like so :`aggregateRoot.MakeTimeShifts()`.

Method signature is very telling. Receiving, modifying elements and returning a collection....

Comment: @Subin use whichever loop suits you, but move each indentation to its respective responsible class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, having this many nested loops indicates that your algorithm could have really bad time complexity. And with the way you're resetting the indexes, I'm not even sure your code is guaranteed to complete. There may be a more efficient algorithm to do what you want, but I'm not going to try to find that.

Second, the `i`, `j`, `k` naming convention for loop variables is okay if you have two or maybe three nested loops. But with six levels, it makes your code much less readable (and more error-prone). You should consider using locals with reasonable names instead of expressions like `TimeLineInit[i].Stage[j].ToolList[m]`. Or even better, `foreach` loops, which basically do the same with less code.

Third, I think the code you're using for resetting is wrong. For example, when `i = 0` and you reset the loop variables, you end up running the innermost loop with `i = 0` and `k = 0`, which should never happen (since the invariant is `k < i`).

Fourth, I think that a method that takes something as a parameter, modifies it and then returns it is a code smell. One exception would be a fluent interface, but that doesn't seem to be your case, since the method is not an extension method.

Fifth, you should use normal .Net naming conventions (e.g. `camelCase` for local variables, instead of `PascalCase`).

Sixth, you should do all your time calculations in `TimeSpan`s, instead of `double`s representing minutes, because it's simpler.

Seventh, I think you could make your code more readable using LINQ.

The whole code would look something like:

```
public void ToolArrangment(List<LCycle> timeLineInit)
{
    foreach (var lifeCycle1 in timeLineInit)
    {
        bool repeat;
        do
        {
            repeat = false;

            var stages = (from stage1 in lifeCycle1.Stage
                          from lifeCycle2 in timeLineInit.TakeWhile(lc2 => lc2 != lifeCycle1)
                          from stage2 in lifeCycle2.Stage
                          from tool1 in stage1.ToolList
                          from tool2 in stage2.ToolList
                          where tool1.ToolName == tool2.ToolName
                          where IsTimeOverLaps(stage1.StageSpan, stage2.StageSpan)
                          select new { stage1, stage2 })
                .FirstOrDefault();

            if (stages != null)
            {
                var replaceStage = stages.stage1.DeepCopy();
                var timeDifference = replaceStage.StageSpan.ToTime - replaceStage.StageSpan.FromTime;
                replaceStage.StageSpan.FromTime = stages.stage2.StageSpan.ToTime;
                replaceStage.StageSpan.ToTime = replaceStage.StageSpan.ToTime + timeDifference;
                LCycleTimeShift(lifeCycle1, replaceStage);
                repeat = true;
            }
        } while (repeat);
    }
}
```

---

I gave it some thought and I think a much more efficient algorithm to do the same is not that difficult. You would have a hash table indexed by `ToolName` and for each tool, you would keep a list of all known stages that use it. You would walk though all tools in all stages in all timelines and add them to the list of stages for that tool. If you couldn't do that because of an overlap, you would move the stage, just like you do right now (if I understand your code correctly).

I haven't though out all the details, but I think something like this should work and be much faster than your solution.

Comment: What the meaning of `.FirstOrDefault();`

Comment: I didn't understand the fourth statement. Were you speaking about `LCycleTimeShift`?

Comment: @SubinJacob You always want to take the first pair of stages that fulfills the conditions, modify the structure accordingly and then start from the beginning. `FirstOrDefault()` is there to get that first pair. If there is no matching pair, it will return `null`, which lets it exist the `do`-`while` cycle.

Comment: @SubinJacob No, I was speaking about `ToolArrangment()`. It takes the whole list as a parameter, modifies some objects inside it and then returns it. That's a pattern that doesn't make much sense, I think.

Comment: But why that pattern doesn't make sense? passing a large data structure is not recommended? why? (I think, you were asking to send only the object that needed for rearrangement)

Comment: @SubinJacob That's not it. It's that there is no reason to return it, since the caller already has the structure. So you should make the `ToolArrangment()` method `void`-returning.

Comment: but only if a reference type, right?

Comment: Once I was advised its better to use value types since it could enhance readability.

Comment: @SubinJacob Yeah, but almost all mutable types in .Net are reference types. And custom value types should be used only very rarely, I'm not sure how would they enhance readability.

Answer (score 2):

This does not reduce nesting per se, but it reduces clutter for all loop variables that are not really used:

```
public List<LCycle> ToolArrangment(List<LCycle> TimeLineInit)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < TimeLineInit.Count; i++) //Each LIfeCycles In TimeLine
    {
        stages:
        for (int k = 0; k < i; k++) //Each LifeCycles Upto Current LifeCycle
            foreach (var stageA in TimeLineInit[i].Stage)
                foreach (var stageB in TimeLineInit[k].Stage)
                    foreach (var toolA in stageA.ToolList)
                        foreach (var toolB in stageB.ToolList)
                        {
                            if ( //If both tools are same (satidfying above for loop conditions)
                                toolA.ToolName == toolB.ToolName
                                //tool using at same time.
                                && IsTimeOverLaps(stageA.StageSpan, stageB.StageSpan))
                            {
                                Stage ReplaceStage = stageA.DeepCopy(); //Taking Copy of stage Span to make time shift
                                Double TimeDifference = (ReplaceStage.StageSpan.ToTime - ReplaceStage.StageSpan.FromTime).TotalMinutes;
                                //Calculating required time shift
                                ReplaceStage.StageSpan.FromTime = stageB.StageSpan.ToTime; //FromTime changed accordingly
                                ReplaceStage.StageSpan.ToTime = ReplaceStage.StageSpan.ToTime.AddMinutes(TimeDifference); //To Time Changed accordingly
                                LCycleTimeShift(TimeLineInit[i], ReplaceStage); //passing refernce

                                goto stages;
                            }
                        }
    }

    return TimeLineInit;
}
```

Comment: http://xkcd.com/292/ ;-)

Comment: @GCATNM: Yeah, but that's a rare specimen of a good `goto`. Seriously it's _the_ reason it's left in the language.

Comment: foreach is recommended for better readabilty! rite?

Comment: @SubinJacob: Yes, IMHO `foreach` yields code that's a lot more readable. Consider `item` vs. `MyWordlyNamedCollectionsCollection[k].Items[i]`.